# Create Azure AD Application Graph API Key using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

Is there is a way to create an Azure AD App Graph API Key using PowerShell as shown below?

I saw some [articles](http://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/managing-azure-ad-application-for-key-vault/) where they create a certificate first but how Azure is generating a key for my App without asking for a certificate when I do it manually? I want to create the same key as Azure doing using PowerShell.

[Azure AD Application Graph API Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X0AF.png)

Thanks,

Comment: There is no such a PowerShell command to add a key to an AD Application. However, it is possible through Graph API. Please read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565276/azure-ad-add-keys-via-azure-cli/36591662#36591662) for a similar question.