# Azure CLI create KEY for an app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

I'm struggeling to find a way how one can add/create a key for the app in Azure AD using CLI?

What I mean by the key is authentication token with the expiry time under AD->App Name->Settings->Keys.

All of the documentation I have found so far is for adding everything but the key as if Microsoft again decided that it's better to **CLICK** like a monkey rather then use CLI or API.

Is this possible, can you create the key through CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a new Azure AD app, you could specify a key with [Azure Cli 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_app_create). For example.

```
az ad app create --display-name "test" --homepage "http://localhost" --identifier-uris "https://localhost" --password "123adfaesdf"
```

You could use `az ad app update` to modify expiry time.

However, currently, Azure Cli does not support add a new key for an existing app. You also could refer to this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565276/azure-ad-add-keys-via-azure-cli).

Comment: In my opinion key should not be called password eventhough it serves this purpose. The annoying bit is that Azure CLI 2.0 has **--key-value** option which can't be used to set the "key value",  when using **--password** option I can't name the key ("key description") which one can again find annoying. Anyway I guess this is the Microsoft way :(.